# Did Grandpa count correctly? Another Grandpa Mystery

Tags: riddle, mathematics, no-computers

Grandpa just returned from a long trip. He started telling me about his adventure in a wild place.

> " I saw animals", he said. "Three different kind"
>
> "Just for fun I counted their limbs"
>
> "You mean legs" I interrupted
>
> " Yeah whatever. There were 26 total animals of 3 different kind. And
>   I counted 26 legs for the 26 animals.
>
> The total number of first kind of animal was 8 times the second kind
>   and 2 times the third kind.
>
> Can you guess what kind of animals I saw and how many of each were
>   there?
>
> And where was I?
>
> By the way, there were no one legged or disabled animals there, just to
>   be clear

Did he count correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I'd say Grandpa was in

> Australia

And he saw

> 16, 8 and 2 animals of three types.  Why?
>  assume the least number was 1.  That makes the largest number 8 and the middle 4.  That's 13, so we should double each number for 16, 8, 2.

Of which

> the 16 can't have two legs (more than 26) and no one legged animals, so they have 0 legs (snakes?)
>  The 8 can't have 3 legs, because the 2 would have to be one legged, so the 8 have 2 legs/limbs.  This could be a wingless bird like a Kiwi. (ok, it has wings but they are so small they are invisible and Grandpa wouldn't have seen them)
>  The 2 have 5 limbs, therefore.  Which a Kangaroo is considered to have, counting it's tail (hence Australia)

Comment: Also, rot13[Ur fnj 26 navznyf, 16 bs juvpu jrer fanxrf. Vs gung qbrfa'g qrfpevor Nhfgenyvn V qba'g xabj jung qbrf.]

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so he said he counted 26 animals

We have that

> • number of type 1 = n 
>  • number of type 2 = n/8 
>  • number of type 3 = n/2 
>  
>  n + n/8 + n/2 = 26, therefore n = 16

so he saw:

> • 16 of type 1 
>  • 2 of type 2 
>  • 8 of type 3

But what were they?

> He saw 16 type 1's, and saw no one legged animals; if type 1 had 2 legs, the minimum allowable, he'd have seen 32 limbs; too many already. So, type 1 has no legs, must be a snake or fish.

from that we have

> (2*x)+(8*y) = 26. Logical numbers are 2 and 4; lets plug them in: 2*4 + 8*2 = 24 thats too low; but if we add 2 legs to either we blow it out...

but he originally said

> limbs, so thats not necessarily in pairs... 2*5 + 8*2 is just right

Thus, he saw

> 16 snakes, fish or other zero-limbed creatures 
>  2 five-limbed creatures. I'm going with starfish, but spider-monkeys with prehensile tails could be another contender 
>  8 two-limbed creatures, this could be anything; flamingoes, chickens etc.

Comment: thanks el-guest; man i'm struggling with spoilerised paragraphs; what a pain!

Comment: Great Logic @crcroberts. But "Where was I?" was the question he asked.